# Is Vector.<Number> impossible to initilize with a numeric array?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flex4

How would you go about initializing a Vector. with say the values 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Logic would say you could do newVector = new Vector. ( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] );

But this gives you an empty vector.

You could also try something like this...

`var tmp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

newVector = new Vector.();

newVector = newVector.concat(tmp);`

But then you get a type error converting Array to Vector.

I'm stumped, am I missing something stupid or does the vector class really not play well with numeric types?  You can try making them decimal numbers just to be sure they get cast as number and not int.

Comment: The problem isn't numeric types, it's your (understandable) assumption that vectors and arrays can be interchangeable. However, they are completely incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just got the syntax wrong.

It should be:

```
        var foo:Vector.<int> = new <int>[3,2,4];
        trace( foo ); // traces "3,2,4"
```

Doing this on the other hand, isn't possible:

```
        var bar:Array = [5, 3, 1];
        var baz:Vector.<int> = new <int>bar; // Syntax Error
```

Comment: Thank you, that was pointed out to me in the documentation yesterday.  .net generics is my native language, so the fact that the compiler accepted new Vector.<blah>([]) threw me off a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done it in the way EyeSeeEm comments, what I do is:

```
var foo:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([3, 2.9, 1]);
```

And it allows to make this:

```
var arr:Array = [3, 2.9, 1];
var foo:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>(arr);
```